# Getting an inserted file from MySQL byte array to actual file content

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have inserted a file into MySQL database as a byte array:

```
preparedStatment.setBytes(10, inpStream.toString().getBytes());
```

I had already gotten the file from the database as a byte array but I'm stuck at getting the actual file's contents. What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The bytes you got from the database *are* the file contents. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Exactly, is the file an image or a pdf or something?  Or are you trying to read text out of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
preparedStatment.setBytes(10, inpStream.toString().getBytes());
```

You are storing the result of the `InputStream#toString()` as bytes in the DB. The `InputStream#toString()` does not return the file's contents as you seem to think, instead it returns the default `classname@hashcode` representation inherited from [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

You need [`PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) instead:

```
preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(10, inpStream);
```

Then you can retrieve it by [`ResultSet#getBinaryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28java.lang.String%29):

```
InputStream inpStream = resultSet.getBinaryStream("columnname");
```

Or if you *really* need `PreparedStatement#setBytes()`, then you would need to write the `InputStream` to a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) the usual way first and then get the bytes by its [`toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29) method. But this is not memory efficient per se.